# Python - different display of words in list, different display as element

Tags: python, utf-8

I have file that contains list of polish words. File encofing is `UTF-8 (with BOM), with CRLF line terminators`. I load whole file with:

```
dictionary = open('file.txt', 'r').readlines()
```

Then, when I want to print single element, it is printed properly:

```
print dictionary[104] -> abakusów
```

But when I want to print array slice I get not decoded bytes in strings, like:

```
print dictionary[104:105] -> ['ABAKUS\xc3\x93W\tabakus\r\n']
```

(there is also base form of given word seperated with tab, but this is not important here). I wonder why is that (especially as I have to get each word's length and I'm not sure if it will be done properly).

Thanks for any hints.

Comment: try `print repr("abakusów")` and you get the same `'abakus\xc3\xb3w'`

Comment: because `list` uses recursive calls to `__repr___` to print objects it contains. It is only a matter of what is printed, but the data is the same.

Comment: try `print dictionary[104:105][0]` or use `print ",",join(list)` to manually convert list elements into one string before you print it.

Comment: BTW: see Polish group on Facebook: [Python: pierwsze kroki](https://www.facebook.com/groups/pythonpierwszekroki/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`print` calls `str` - a string representation - for its parameter. This works nicely when you just print a single string. In the second case `str` is called for a list of strings, but the list datatype does not use `str` to build the string representation of its sub-elements but `repr`. This is why you get the unencoded *escaped* representation. You have to either use indexing or a loop to print single elements of the list or program your own function for getting a nicer string representation for lists. For example, this:

```
def mystr(list):
    return '[' + ', '.join(['"' + str(e) + '"' for e in list]) + ']'
```